# Stanford coreNLP output.printSingletonEntities parameter doesn't work

Tags: parameters, stanford-nlp

I'm using coreNLP for coreference resolution from command line. I need the system to annotate singletons (single mentions) to be able to evaluate the output on my data, which has them annotated. I know that the system was trained on Ontonotes, which doesn't have singletons, but I found this parameter  **output.printSingletonEntities** which is supposed, I guess, to add singletons annotation in some heuristic way.

**output.printSingletonEntities : Boolean. Whether to print singleton entity mentions in coreference output.**

However, adding it into the parameters file changed absolutely nothing.
**What am I doing wrong?**

### This is my parameter file:

annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,coref

tokenize.whitespace = true

tokenize.options = tokenizePerLine

ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak = always

coref.algorithm = neural

filelist = /Users/veronika/Dropbox/data/preprocessing/filelist.txt

output.printSingletonEntities = true

---

*I also tried to call it from command line directly, but the annotation stays the same.*

*java -cp "*" -Xmx10g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props /Users/veronika/Dropbox/data/sampleProps.properties -output.printSingletonEntities true*

Thank you in advance for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add in `-coref.removeSingletonClusters false` to your settings.